# I have to install Ubuntu on ASUS TUF GTX 1050 , but issue regarding drivers on Wimdows 10

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-geforce, ubuntu-drivers

I have a problem with drivers , cause on my Windows 10, Wifi works for a couple of minutes, then disappears, and the problem is sometimes keyboard auto types. These all issues are due to the drivers. My laptop is 9 months old. I know there isn't any hardware problem. Are the same Windows drivers installed on Ubuntu drivers or it is different?. If different. Then I, think , should install Ubuntu soon.

Comment: The Ubuntu Desktop installer includes a "Try Ubuntu" option (that does NOT touch your Windows install) specifically to answer hardware compatibility questions like this. Use it.

Comment: "I know there isn't any hardware problem" how do you know that? I would assume if drivers are acting up it IS a hardware problem. Those are the connectors to hardware and do not really like unexpected behaviour.